# Deploy multiple production environment

Tags: iis, .net-core, msdeploy, webdeploy

I want to deploy an Asp.NetCore MVC application to many environment (development, staging, production, pre-production...).

For that, i planned to use the environment variables and the different appsetting.{environment}.json to configure the different connexion strings for each environment.

My problem is that I have multiple production environments, so how can I differenciate each configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "For that, i planned to use the environment variables and the different appsetting.{environment}.json to configure the different connexion strings for each environment." Why cannot you do the same for multiple production environments?

Comment: I though environment were predefined by dot net and could only be production staging and development but is seems i can do as enrivonment as i want..

Comment: If the doc uses "Staging" and "Staging_2" as example, I think you can go "Production" and "Production_2" at least, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2